# Allow VIEWS accessing PARAGRAPHS fields collection

Tags: views, 8, entities, paragraphs

I have a content type called "**Slideshow**" where users can create any number of "**slideshow**" nodes.
This content type has a field called "**Slide**" which is a field collection of other fields (caption, image, description, and link). The user can add multiple "**Slides**" to each "**Slideshow**" node  (I can achieve this with the help of either PARAGRAPHS or FIELD COLLECTION modules).

Then I use VIEWS to create Blocks of the "**Slideshow**" content type to display specific nodes using contextual filter **Nid**.

MY PROBLEM IS:
In VIEWS I can only list "title" and "**slide**" fields (as  rendered) of the "**slideshow**" content type, whereas I need to list the fields inside the "**Slide**" field (the caption, image, description and link) so that I can customize them using VIEWS.
Is there any way to achieve this? (allowing VIEWS to access the fields of PARAGRAPHS module).

POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:
In VIEWS I added a relationship "**Slide**", this allowed me to list the fields inside "**Slide**" field. the problem is that I'm trying to avoid relationships as it uses a lot of LEFT JOINS and this may decrease performance.
my website uses lots of these slideshows and galleries multiple time in the same page and I don't want to lose performance.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In D8 your View's are automatically cached; thus, your query is results are cached, so I wouldn't worry too much about this. Nonetheless, you can enable `Show performance statistics` in views settings (`/admin/structure/views/settings`), to see how long it takes.

Testing with 1 field, the View Render Time is ~1.20ms faster when you create a View of Show: Field Collection Item and then add relationship to node rather than a View of Show: Content with a relationship of field collection.